# Skip String if null

Tags: c#, xml, api

I am writing a program that calls an API, receives XML and displays the tracking aswell as opening a web browser with tracking info in. I have a problem, if the wrong tracking id is entered the nodes return `null` and the string will be `null`, how can I display an error rather than throwing a null ref exception?

```cs
//ONLINE PORTAL TRACKING
string ConNo = Con.Text;

XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load(url1 + ConNo + url2 + APIKEY);
XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/Response/Detail/Data");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string ConsignmentNumber = node["ConNo"].InnerText;
    string tracking_url = node["tracking_url"].InnerText;
    string Lifts = node["Lifts"].InnerText;
    string TrackingID = node["TrackingID"].InnerText;
    string JobStatus = node["Status"].InnerText;
    string Barcodes = node["Barcodes"].InnerText;
    string Weight = node["Weight"].InnerText;
    string DateMan = node["DateEntered"].InnerText;

    this.ConsignmentNumber.Text = ConsignmentNumber;
    this.Lifts.Text = Lifts;
    // this.TrackingURL.Text = tracking_url;
    this.TrackingID.Text = TrackingID;
    this.JobStatus.Text = JobStatus;
    this.Barcodes.Text = Barcodes;
    this.Weight.Text = Weight;
    this.DelMan.Text = DateMan;

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PortalURL1 + TrackingID);
```

Comment: Not a C# expert myself, but this applies to most languages. Check the stacktrace for the exception. Wrap the code where the exception occurs in a try catch. Inside the catch return your own exception or errorpage.

Comment: `node["ConNo"].InnerText` assumes `node["ConNo"]` exists (is not null). Try `node["ConNo"]?.InnerText` to return `null` rather than crash

Comment: Have you considered simply “checking” to see if the id is `null` BEFORE you try and use it? If it is `null` then pop-up an error message or what ever you want to do and continue.

Comment: Also, I do not see “where” you would get a `null` exception in the posted code. The code … `this.TrackingID.Text = TrackingID;` … is NOT going to throw an `null` exception even if `TrackingID` IS `null.` It is perfectly fine to set a text boxes `Text` to `null`. Are you 100% sure the `null` exception is coming from the `TrackingID` … ? …

Comment: Use count : nodes.Count() > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get some information in the XML response in case of error. Something like this:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/Response/Detail/Data");
if (nodes == null)
{
    // Look the root content to see if contains a node with the error. 
    // In that case, do a SelectSingleNode. Here is an example with a 
    // sample path (is not real, I don't know anything about the XML 
    // error response schema)
    XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("/Response/Detail/Error");
    var error = node?.InnerText;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        // If for any reason we can't get any error...
        error = $"Unknown error on query: {ConNo}";
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```